# AutoHotkey: Syntax For Mapping CapsLock to Alt-Tab?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

In [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com), I would like to map CapsLock to Alt-Tab. What is the syntax to make this work? And must I reboot to see it start working?

(I've tried writing `CapsLock::AltTab` -- is this the wrong syntax?)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official AutoHotKey documentation on Hotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm):

> Each Alt-Tab hotkey must be a combination of two keys, which is typically achieved via the ampersand symbol (&).

It goes on to give the following example:

```
LCtrl & CapsLock::AltTab
```

Regarding rebooting, that is completely unnecessary with any AutoHotKey script as far as I am aware.

Comment: If I want binding capslook on next alt tab ?